# cURL session issue

Tags: php, html, curl

```
<?php
session_start();

//create array of data to be posted
//traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)
//set POST variables
    $url = 'xxx/cart2.php';
    $fields = array(
        'ssl_merchant_id' => ('xxx'),
        'ssl_user_id' => ('xxx'),
        'ssl_pin' => ('xxx'),
        'ssl_transaction_type' => ('xxx'),
        'confirm_code' => ($_POST['confirm_code']),
        'ssl_show_form' => ('xxx'),
        'ssl_cardholder_ip' => ($_POST['ssl_cardholder_ip']),
        'ssl_amount' => ($_POST['ssl_amount'])
    );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init('xxx/cart2.php');

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;

?>
```

Every time this code loads, it is creating a new session! How do I go about preventing a new session from being loaded each time? This was just a script that I found and modified for my own use as I have never worked with cURL before.

Comment: What do you mean its starting a new session?

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Create a writable text file called "cookie.txt". You will need this to save the session data returned from cURL.

```
$cookie_file = "cookie.txt";
if (!file_exists($cookie_file)) {
    $handle = fopen($cookie_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$cookie_file);
}
if (!is_writable($cookie_file) && !chmod($cookie_file, 0777)) {
    die ("chmod() failed on file $cookie_file");
}
```

Here set the options and tell cURL where to save the cookie data.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
```

So that after you post the form with cURL, the session data will be saved and it will not load a new session every time you run the script.

Comment: I already have a session written though.  the curl page creates a new session and then the next page converts back to the session I had set.  why is this?

Comment: @user2227936 When you use `session_start()`, it creates a session on your site or use the existing one. The session information is stored in the cookies of your browser. When you do a cURL to fetch a page and submit a form, what you are actually doing is to fetch contents from **another** site (even though it can be the same site) with your php page acting as a **proxy**. Thus you need to define a cookie file to save the session information for that other site.